# Laravel Eloquent orWherePivot Not Returning Expected Result

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have an eloquent query where I am not getting the expected results and I was hoping someone could explain to me what the correct way to write the query.

I have three tables:

```
records (belongsToMany users)
users (belongsToMany records)
record_user (pivot)
```

The `record_user` table also has a column for `role`.

I attempt to get all the records where the user has the `role` of either `singer` or `songwriter`:

```
$results = User::find(Auth::user()->id)
                    ->records()
                    ->wherePivot('role', 'singer')
                    ->orWherePivot('role', 'songwriter')
                    ->get();
```

Below is how the SQL syntax is generated:

```
select `records`.*, `record_user`.`user_id` as `pivot_user_id`,
`record_user`.`record_id` as `pivot_record_id` from `records` 
inner join `record_user` on `records`.`id` = `record_user`.`property_id` 
where
`record_user`.`user_id` = '1' and `record_user`.`role` = 'singer' or 
`record_user`.`role` = 'songwriter'
```

The results for `singer` role are what is expected: All records where the user is the singer. The problem is the results for the `songwriter`: I am getting ALL songwriters and the query is not constrained by the `user_id`. For some reason I was expecting the `songwriter` role to also be constrained by the `user_id` - what is the correct way to write this using the eloquent syntax?

Comment: So what is it exactly you are trying to get? all records where user is either songwriter or singer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmm..I think you need to use an advanced where clause.

```
$results = Auth::user()
            ->records()
            ->where(function($query) {
                $query->where('record_user.role', '=', 'singer')
                      ->orWhere('record_user.role', '=', 'songwriter');
            })
            ->get();
```

Comment: Yes, the advance where clause fixed the issue and resulted in a query where the roles were bracketed `(...)` together: `and ('record_user'.'role' = 'singer' or 'recored_user'.'role' = 'songwriter')`. I'm still a little confused why it did not function this way in the first place. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

It is Laravel issue. In my case I solve it like this:

```
$results = Auth::user()
                 ->records()
                 ->wherePivot('role', 'singer')
                 ->orWherePivot('role', 'songwriter')
                 ->where('user_id', Auth::id())
                 ->get();
```

Or use advance where clause

Answer (score 0):

If your trying to get records I would do something similar to this:

```
User::find(Auth::user()->id)
    ->records()
    ->where(function($q){
        $q->where('records.role', 'singer')
            ->orWhere('records.role', 'songwriter');
    })->get();
```